# Display name from mysql table with highest amount

Tags: php, mysql

An example of my table is this:

```
---------------------------------------------
id | fistname      | lastname     |  score 
---------------------------------------------
1  | bob           | wilson       | 77 
2  | jess          | farr         | 47
```

I need a way of displaying the name with the highest  / lowest and average score in php

UPDATE :: I have this code in php , but it just returns Resource id #5

```
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

$sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM students ORDER BY english DESC LIMIT 1 ";
mysql_select_db('education');
$score = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

echo $score;
```

Comment: Where is your php code about query?

Comment: I dont know how to do the code in php . I was hoping someone could point me in the right dorection

Comment: You should start with teading some tutorials then, and when you find any problem with code, so we will be here to help

Comment: Get started by reading through http://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_mysql_select.asp - Start by basic selecting data and then try to order by highest / lowest, then work out your average as well.

Comment: @Fabio I have added php code

Answer (score 1):

How about doing this in SQL?

```
 SELECT firstname, lastname 
   FROM scoretable
  ORDER BY score DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

That will give you the first and last name of the one with the highest score.  It doesn't work correctly if you have two people with the same highest score, but you didn't ask for that.

If you need all the people who are tied for highest score, try this.

```
 SELECT firstname, lastname
   FROM scoretable
  WHERE score = (SELECT MAX(score) FROM scoretable)
```

Comment: so , how would i display this as an echo in php

Comment: iv added some php code which uses your mysql code , but i didnt work

Answer (score 1):

For thw Highest you can try this

`SELECT * FROM (table name) WHERE score = (SELECT MAX(score) FROM (table name))`

and for lowest you can try this as well:

`SELECT * FROM (table name) WHERE score = (SELECT MIN(score) FROM (table name))`

Answer (score 0):

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('YOURDB NAME');
$highest= mysql_query("SELECT firstname, max(score)FROM table_name");
$lowest = mysql_query("SELECT firstname, min(score)FROM table_name");
$avg = mysql_query("SELECT firstname, avg(score)FROM table_name");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($highest);
echo $row[0];
echo $row[1];
```

Comment: Man the use of mysql_* function are discouraged because they are deprecated

Comment: I think you should lack knowledge of Php.

Comment: Haha please see the BIG RED BOX in documentation http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: This is not the point, i did not say it would not work actually, just that you are using an old deprecated and no longer maintained api

Comment: It's not a battle, i just advised you

Comment: what if there is more than one person with a high score ?

Comment: use mysql_fetch_array intends of mysql_fetch_row and put into while loop